# How to show the below is an improper integral

Tags: integration

How would you prove the following integral diverges:
$\int_0^1\theta^{-1}(1-\theta)^{c-1} d\theta $ for any constant c>0

Comment: You would integrate it and evaluate the limits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\begin{array}\\
\int_0^1t^{-1}(1-t)^{c-1} dt
&\gt \int_0^{\frac12}t^{-1}(1-t)^{c-1} dt\\
&= \int_0^{\frac12}t^{-1}\frac{(1-t)^{c}}{1-t} dt\\
&\gt \int_0^{\frac12}t^{-1}(\frac12)^{c} dt\\
&= \frac1{2^c}\int_0^{\frac12}t^{-1} dt\\
\end{array}
$

and this diverges because
$\lim_{x \to 0}\int_x^{\frac12}t^{-1} dt
=\lim_{x \to 0}(\ln(\frac12)-\ln(x))
\to \infty$.